# LCM and HCF program: strange behavior in an assignment

Tags: c

I've just started practicing arrays in C, and I got stuck with a strange behavior in this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void factorize (unsigned int num, unsigned int arr_exps[], size_t nexps);
void MCD (unsigned int arr_fact1[], size_t nfact1, unsigned int arr_fact2[], size_t nfact2,
          unsigned int arr_fact_com[], size_t nfact_com);
void mcm (unsigned int arr_fact1[], size_t nfact1, unsigned int arr_fact2[], size_t nfact2,
          unsigned int arr_fact_all[], size_t nfact_all);

int main (void) {

    unsigned int factAll[100] = {0};
    unsigned int factCom[100] = {0};
    unsigned int exps1[100] = {0};
    unsigned int exps2[100] = {0};
    
    unsigned int n1, n2;
    

    puts("Ciao! Questo e' un programma per il calcolo del MCD e del mcm.");
    printf("%s", "Inserisci due numeri: ");
    scanf("%u %u", &n1, &n2);
    factorize(n1, exps1, 100);
    factorize(n2, exps2, 100);

    unsigned int mcd = 1, mcc = 1;

        MCD(exps1, 100, exps2, 100, factCom, 100);

            for(unsigned int l = 0; l <= 100; l++) {
                if(factCom[l] != 0) {
                    mcd = mcd * pow(l, factCom[l]);
                }
            }
            if(mcd == 0) {
                printf("\n%u e %u sono primi tra loro. ", n1, n2);
                puts("MCD = 1.");
            }
                else {
                    printf("\nMCD = %u", mcd);
                }

        mcm(exps1, 100, exps2, 100, factAll, 100);

        for(unsigned int h = 0; h <= 100; h++) {
            if(factAll[h] != 0) {
                unsigned int test = pow(h, factAll[h]);   // <----------------- THIS TWO LINES HERE
                printf("%u ", test);                      // <-----------------
                mcc = mcc * pow(h, factAll[h]);
            }
        }

            printf("\nmcm = %u", mcc);


        

}
    void factorize (unsigned int num, unsigned int arr_exps[], size_t nexps) {

        printf("\n%u = ", num);

        unsigned int is_primeF = 1;     /* Flag per indicare se il fattore è primo o no */
        unsigned int is_firstF = 1;     /* Flag per il primo fattore da scrivere */

        /* Inizializza a zero l'array */
        for(unsigned int j = 0; j <= nexps; j++) {
            arr_exps[j] = 0;
        }

        for(unsigned int i = 2; i <= num; i++) {
            is_primeF = 1;
            for(unsigned int j = 2; j <= i/2; j++) {   /* Il fattore considerato i è primo? */
                if(i % j == 0) {
                    is_primeF = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
                if(is_primeF == 1) {
                    while(num % i == 0) {
                        arr_exps[i]++;
                        num = num / i;
                    }
                }
        }

        for(unsigned int k = 0; k <= nexps; k++) {  /* Stampa la scomposizione */
            if(arr_exps[k] != 0) {
                if(is_firstF == 1) {
                    printf("%u^%u", k, arr_exps[k]);
                    is_firstF = 0;
                } 
                    else if(is_firstF == 0) {
                        printf("%s", " * ");
                        printf("%u^%u", k, arr_exps[k]);

                    }
            }
        }
    }

    void MCD (unsigned int arr_fact1[], size_t nfact1, unsigned int arr_fact2[], size_t nfact2,
                       unsigned int arr_fact_com[], size_t nfact_com) {

        for(unsigned int j = 0; j <= nfact_com; j++) {
            arr_fact_com[j] = 0;
        }
                           
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < nfact1; i++) {
            if(arr_fact1[i] != 0) {         // Il fattore è presente nel primo numero?
                if(arr_fact2[i] != 0) {     // Il fattore è presente nel secondo numero?
                    if (arr_fact1[i] < arr_fact2[i]) {
                        arr_fact_com[i] = arr_fact1[i];
                    }
                        else {
                            arr_fact_com[i] = arr_fact2[i];
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void mcm (unsigned int arr_fact1[], size_t nfact1, unsigned int arr_fact2[], size_t nfact2,
          unsigned int arr_fact_all[], size_t nfact_all) {

            for(unsigned int h = 0; h <= nfact_all; h++) {
            arr_fact_all[h] = 0;
            }

        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < nfact1; i++) {
                if(arr_fact1[i] != 0 && arr_fact1[i] > arr_fact_all[i]) {
                    arr_fact_all[i] = arr_fact1[i];
                }
        }
        for(unsigned int j = 0; j < nfact2; j++) {
                if(arr_fact2[j] != 0 && arr_fact2[j] > arr_fact_all[j]) {
                    arr_fact_all[j] = arr_fact2[j];
                }
        }        
    }
```

The code works perfectly if compiled as it's written up here, but those two lines were there just for checking, so I want to remove them. Problem is, I noticed that on removal the code stops working...
The *for* instruction just checks for non-zero entries in the array that contains every factor of the numbers, and then pows and adds every term to the *mcc* variable.
I'm sorry if there are other errors or stupid parts but I'm new to C.
P.S. I can translate comments if needed.

Comment: When `h` equals `100` you are accessing the array `factAll` out of bounds.

Comment: Same with `factCom[l]`, maybe other places too. Your loops should have condition `< 100` instead of `<=`

Comment: Can't believe this was the problem, I thought I checked every single index to avoid these kind of errors. The code works perfectly now. Thank you very much!